# Is it possible to have a negative skin test for tuberculosis and a positive QuantiFERON -TB Gold In-Tube Test?

Tags: tuberculosis

Is it possible to have a negative skin test for tuberculosis and a positive QuantiFERON -TB Gold In-Tube Test?

If so, what does it mean, assuming a PA-LAT chest x-ray on the same patient is negative?